# Create zip with a precise fixed size

Tags: language-agnostic, zip, archive

I'd like to create a zip file with a specific size, *e.g.* 10.000.000 byte.
Let's say that I have to zip a number of files, and they sum up to 8.123.456 byte (random number) once zipped.
I'd like to add "rubbish" to reach **exactly** the size I chose (10Mb in this case).

Of course I'm assuming the files I have to zip do not exceed my limit.

I don't have any specific language requirement to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just concatenate a "rubbish" file and a valid Zip file that match together your 10Mb.
The Zip format was made for such situations. Typically, you can concatenate an executable and a Zip file for making an installer or a self-extracting archive.

Here an example (I concatenate a randomly chosen GIF and a Zip). The Info-Zip unzip tool says:

```
unzip -v appended.zip
Archive:  appended.zip
warning [appended.zip]:  1772887 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
 Length   Method    Size  Ratio   Date   Time   CRC-32    Name
--------  ------  ------- -----   ----   ----   ------    ----
     186  Defl:N      140  25%  15.02.12 12:03  56202537  zip-ada/debg_za.cmd
     349  Defl:N      202  42%  10.02.12 22:19  7718ccec  zip-ada/debug.pra
    4357  Defl:N     1381  68%  24.09.16 06:43  30f2fef0  zip-ada/demo/demo_csv_into_zip.adb
    1015  Defl:N      513  50%  02.10.18 15:49  f0edcf97  zip-ada/demo/demo_unzip.adb
     603  Defl:N      310  49%  20.03.16 08:26  b3906614  zip-ada/demo/demo_zip.adb
  161483  Defl:N    39845  75%  27.08.16 16:35  9f24d1fe  zip-ada/doc/appnote.txt
...
```

The decompression test is successful (as expected):

```
unzip -t appended.zip
Archive:  appended.zip
warning [appended.zip]:  1772887 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
    testing: zip-ada/debg_za.cmd      OK
    testing: zip-ada/debug.pra        OK
    testing: zip-ada/demo/demo_csv_into_zip.adb   OK
    testing: zip-ada/demo/demo_unzip.adb   OK
    testing: zip-ada/demo/demo_zip.adb   OK
    testing: zip-ada/doc/appnote.txt   OK
    testing: zip-ada/doc/lzma-specification.txt   OK
...
No errors detected in compressed data of appended.zip.
```

Comment: Is there any way to concatenate using zip commands? Or should I code a concatenation with another file or string?

Comment: Just append the Zip file after the "rubbish" file. With the Windows command line (cmd.exe) it is, in my example: copy /b rubbish.gif + archive.zip appended.zip

Comment: Very nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the zipped data in another file formatted as:

```
<zip file length><zip file content><random data until size is as required>
```

You know the number of random data because it is the rquired size minus the length of the file minus the size of file length representation.

To unzip, just reverst the process.

Comment: What do you mean with "wrap"? Can you provide a practical example please?

Answer (score 0):

You can add you "rubbish" file without compression **within** your target Zip file.
The added size will be the "rubbish" file's size, plus 76 bytes, plus twice the "rubbish" file's name's length. Some zipping tools add extra metadata on top of that.